# How to fetch only the documents that have 3 different values in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following data in mongodb:

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("111"),
        "id" : "111",
        "classification" : [ 
            {
                "annotator" : "annotatorName1",
                "category" : "white"
            }, 
            {
                "annotator" : "annotatorName2",
                "category" : "white"
            }, 
            {
                "annotator" : "annotatorName3",
                "category" : "black"
            }
        ]
    }

   {
        "_id" : ObjectId("222"),
        "id" : "222",
        "classification" : [ 
                   {
                "annotator" : "annotatorName1",
                "category" : "white"
            }, 
            {
                "annotator" : "annotatorName2",
                "category" : "blue"
            }, 
            {
                "annotator" : "annotatorName3",
                "category" : "black"
            }
        ]
    }

  {
        "_id" : ObjectId("333"),
        "kind" : "youtube#video",
        "etag" : "tagvalue",
        "id" : "333"
    }
```

Please note that the `classification` label **does not exists in all my records**, as shown in record with id: "333".

I need to get all the records from my database that have different `category` values. 
So, I need a query that when I run it, I will only get the record that has the `classification` label, and has **exactly 3 different** `category` values, in this case, I want a query that will only return this to me:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("222"),
        "id" : "222",
        "classification" : [ 
            {
                "annotator" : "annotatorName1",
                "category" : "white"
            }, 
            {
                "annotator" : "annotatorName2",
                "category" : "blue"
            }, 
            {
                "annotator" : "annotatorName3",
                "category" : "black"
            }
        ]
    }
```

What command should I enter in my terminal in order to get all the records that have **3 unique** `category` values under `classification`, IFF `classification` exists?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below aggregate can be used to find out the "id"s which have exactly 3 unique categories:

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
  {$match : {classification : {$exists : true}}},
  {$unwind: "$classification"},
  {$group: { _id: "$id", uniqueCategories: {$addToSet: "$classification.category"}}},
  {$project: {_id : 1, numberOfCategories: {$size: "$uniqueCategories"}} },
  {$match: {numberOfCategories: 3} }
])
```

Explanation: We start with matching documents which have the *classification* element. Then we $unwind it so as to deconstruct the embedded array into separate documents. Then it is grouped by id, and using `$addToSet` the categories are collected into an array - this takes care of eliminating any dupes. Then we project its `$size` and match on 'equal to 3'.

This aggregate will yield documents with the _id set to the id field of the documents in your collection that have 3 unique categories, which you can use to get to the documents. If your collection size is quite large, you should consider adding another `$match` stage in the beginning to restrict the dataset. As it stands now, it will be doing a collection scan.

Comment: But Bajal, it always fetches only 50.. I know there are more than 50. I want it to retrieve all of them with different classification categories. Why is it only fetching 50?

Comment: I am guessing you are using robo-3t? It is a limitation of that tool: See: https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/issues/1157
You can run this on the shell and iterate. Or if you execute from any code you will get full results. 
Don't forget to accept/upvote if this helped :)

Comment: I accepted it but it won't let me upvote since I don't have much reputation. Thank you very much for your answer. This solved my problem! :)